# lastModified date format to UK standard

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display when a webpage was last loaded and need to alter the format of the date from 05/18/2015 11:47:39  to 18/05/2015 thanks I am currently using the following :

```
<script language="Javascript">

document.write("last refreshed: " + document.lastModified +"");
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: You can convert lastModified to `Date`, then do `.toLocaleDateString('en-UK')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a function that formats a date to your required format:

```
function formatAsUKDate(date) {
  var day = padWithZero(date.getDate(), 2);
  var month = padWithZero(date.getMonth()+1, 2);
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  return  day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
}

function padWithZero(str, minLength) {
  str = String(str);
  while (str.length < minLength) {
    str = '0' + str;
  }
  return str;
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<script language="Javascript">

document.write("last refreshed: " + formatAsUKDate(document.lastModified) +"");
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Date` object, as:

`var d = new Date("05/18/2015 11:47:39");`

Then retrieve the data as you want it.

Such as `d.getMonth()+1`;

Then finally concatenate as you wish.